# JavaScript on Bootstrap 5 bug

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am not sure why the below JS will not work on my Bootstrap page. I am getting this code straight from an online tutorial and I cannot seem to get it to work the way the instructor does. The console is telling me he issue is on the 3 line of the below script.

```
if (error != "")
                {
            $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"
            role="alert"><strong> There was error(s) in your form:</strong>'
            + error+ '</div>');
        
            }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _cannot seem to get it to work_. What is suppose to happen that isn't? What isn't happening that is supposed to ?

Comment: My guess is : You are defining your string on multiple lines. You should place it all on one line. Or close it and add a plus sign ( + ) before returing on the other line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code without line breaks:

```js
  if (error != "") {
    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role = "alert" > <strong> There was error(s) in your form:</strong>' + error + '</div>');
  }
});
```